# InfoPath forms visable to owners only

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I have created an InfoPath form that has a subsection that is for admin/owners to fill out only. I am looking for a way so that the subsection for admin/owners only shows up when the admin/owner is logged in to the sharepoint site. If the user is not an admin/owner then they only see the first part of the form. Is their a way to do this in InfoPath. I have looked in to making rules for the subsection but not really finding what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide things in InfoPath based on groups using 2 web services. UserProfileService.asmx to get the current logged user and UserGroup.asmx to check the group where the current user belongs to. You need to create a SharePoint group that will be restricted. For example, Restrict Users. Add the users that you wanted to be restricted. Set a rule that will hide the section if the current logged user is within that group (Restrict Users)

See this blog post for the detailed steps. It is a long one.

http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group